# Convert user input String to MenuItem.Shortcut

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, shortcut, mainmenu

I have written an extension framework for an app, and I would like the user to be able to setup keyboard shortcuts for their extension to be run.

When I add the MenuItem to the MainMenu Control at runtime, I would like to be able to use Crtl+N, for example, to run the extension instead of having to click the MenuItem with the mouse or keyboard.

But the problem is I don't know how to convert the user's string value to a [MenuItem.Shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menuitem.shortcut).

For example, here is the keyboard shortcut the user has chosen `"Ctrl+N"`

How do I convert this somehow to a `MenuItem.Shortcut`? I cannot find anything on MSDN about this. I've read the documentation.

Comment: My point is I don't know what keyboard shortcut the user will choose when writing his or her extension, therefore I cannot just hard-code it to something like `menuItem.Shortcut = Shortcut.CtrlN;`.

Comment: You could let the user select from the provided enum.

Comment: @hijinxbassist how do I do this?

Comment: Beware that MainMenu is obsolete and is not available in .NET5+.  MenuStrip and ToolStripMenuItem are the recommended alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* parse the user input as string with something like:

```
var shortcut = Enum.Parse(typeof(Shortcut), "CtrlN");
```

but I suggest you don't do that. You force the user to enter something like `CtrlShiftF10`, with the correct case, otherwise the input fails validation.
A dedicated interface, similar to the [Shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.shortcut) converter shown in the PropertyGrid would be better, so you don't force the User to guess what to write and avoid typos.

But you can also assign the Shortcut enumerator's values (which represent a combination of `Keys`) to, e.g., the DataSource of a ComboBox, so you let the User select one of the entries.

For example, using the [MainMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mainmenu) Component (deprecated in .Net Core 3.1+), get the values of the Shortcut enumerator, then set the `Shortcut` Property of a MenuItem:

```
someComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Shortcut));
someComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += (s, e) => 
    { var selectedShortcut = (Shortcut)(s as ComboBox).SelectedItem; };
```

Using a [MenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menustrip) Control, you have to cast `SelectedItem` to `Keys` instead. The Shortcut enumerator is available in .Net, so the code remains the same (except the cast):

```
// [...]
someComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += (s, e) => 
    { var selectedKeys = (Keys)(s as ComboBox).SelectedItem; };
```